# swift : PickerView selectedRow(inComponent:0) doesnt return -1 when nothing selected

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

swift : PickerView selectedRow(inComponent:0) doesn't return -1 when nothing selected.It returns 0.Once a selection is made it returns the selected index.But thereafter if i open pickerview and if i didnt select anything in pickerview,it returns previously selected index.Why?

MyCode Snippet

```
 @IBAction func selectedRowIsBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let pickerView : UIPickerView = myTextField.inputView as! UIPickerView
    let selectedRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    print("selectedRow =",selectedRow)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using the same instance of `UIPickerView` in `myTextField.inputView` (inputView returns the same `UIPickerView` in it's previous state). Thus, the previous state of picker is preserved.